# Re-order cards in a FITS header

Tags: python-3.x, astropy, fits

I'm trying to modify a FITS image and modify its header accordingly, then save it into a new FITS file

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename

# Open FITS file
image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')
cube = fits.open(image_file)[0]

# Modify the cube
cube.header.remove('NAXIS2')

# ...

cube.header['NAXIS2'] = 5

# Save the new FITS file
hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(cube.data)
hdu.header = cube.header
hdu.writeto('new.fits', overwrite=True)
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
VerifyError: 
Verification reported errors:
HDU 0:
    'NAXIS2' card at the wrong place (card 159).
    'EXTEND' card at the wrong place (card 160).
Note: astropy.io.fits uses zero-based indexing.
```

How do I put the cards in the right order in the header ? Or is there a way to set a card directly at the right place ?

---

Note : this is obviously not the best way to modify a field in the header, but it is the shortest example that reproduces the error that I'm getting. 
I don't want to know how to modify a field, I want to know how to get a new field in the right place in the header.

Comment: What specifically were you trying to do in the first place? Normally it is unnecessary, even undesirable to *manually* manipulate header keywords that represent the data structure precisely because these have to be very exact, and normally users shouldn't have to think about it. You can let the library handle it for you in most cases. See further discussion in https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/3836#issuecomment-470093861

Comment: In most cases it should suffice to assign an array to the `hdu.data` attribute, and when you write out the HDU to a file it will update the header with the correct keywords to correctly represent the data in the file.

Comment: @Iguananaut I am assembling several 2d images into a single 3d cube, and saving that into a new FITS file. Most of the information in the 2d image header is relevant for the 3d cube. But I also need the 'NAXIS3' card.

Comment: Try just doing `fits.PrimaryHDU(cube.data, header)`. It will generally preserve all the metadata keywords from the header while rewriting all the structural keywords to fit the data. In most cases you should not have to manually manipulate `NAXIS` keywords to fit the data, and in fact it's best not to.

Comment: @Iguananaut Would fits.`ImageHDU(cube.data, header)` also preserve all the metadata keywords while rewriting structural keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Header` class has an `insert` function, that makes it possible to add a card before or after a given card.

```
cube.header.insert('EXTEND', ('NAXIS2', 5))
```

will add the `'NAXIS2'` card with value `5` just before the `'EXTEND'` card.

By using the `after=True` keyword, it is also possible to set a new card right after a given card. So an other way of doing the same thing is:

```
cube.header.insert('NAXIS1', ('NAXIS2', 5), after=True)
```

---

With this modification, `hdu.writeto(...)` no longer throws an error.

Comment: You can do this of course to reorder your own header keywords as desired, but as I wrote above you should rarely, if ever, have to manipulate the *standard* FITS headers that represent the array data (e.g. `NAXIS*` or `BTYPE`. This is more useful for the more "metadata" keywords (observer, etc.) which don't necessarily have a standard ordering prescribed. The problem with FITS is it mixes information that describes the binary structure of the file itself along with metadata in the same "header" structure without making a clear distinction between these types of data.